# amCharts: Help with WPF MVVM Data Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, amcharts

Looking a bit of help with Data Binding here and amCharts, through MVVM.  At the minute I have:

An ObservableCollection, named AskCollection

This is a collection of SymbolObjectModels

Each Model contains a:

```
public double Size { get; set; }
public double BidAsk { get; set; }
public string QuoteID { get; set; }
```

Currently I'm attempting to bind the data in the XAML as follows, with no luck:

```
<xaml>
    <am:LineChart Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SeriesSource="{Binding AskCollection}" IDMemberPath="{Binding QuoteID}" Background="DimGray">
                <am:LineChart.Graphs>
                    <am:LineChartGraph DataItemsSource="{Binding AskCollection}" ValueMemberPath="{Binding BidAsk}" SeriesIDMemberPath="{Binding QuoteID}">
                    </am:LineChartGraph>
                </am:LineChart.Graphs>
    </am:LineChart>
</xaml>
```

Unfortunately, there is no Line Chart appearing :(  I also tried with a List opposed to an ObservableCollection, still no joy.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Much appreciated,  Cheers.

Comment: Is this a normal wpf application or are you trying to rendering out to XPS. Just asking because we ran into a similar issue using MVVM so it would work as an xml reporting solution, the problem we ran into was that amcharts does a lot of stuff OnLoad which isn't called when you render to xaml so we had to buy source rights and fix a lot of those details to be lazy load and then it worked great. Otherwise AMCharts should bind just fine if it's a normal WPF app.

Comment: Hi jbtule, thanks for the reply.  I actually just had to google what XPS was, so I can assure you it's just a normal WPF application :)  Though, funny you should mention the subject of OnLoad, in the tutorial, where they use code behind, they had their code in a:private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) event handler, I'm not sure if this is what you are referring to, or whether it would affect the Binding, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Are you sure the DataContext has been set on the WPF UserControl? I'd recommend using a WPF spy application such as WPF Inspector (http://www.wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html) to check these things. Alternatively, flesh the properties out with an implementation and breakpoint them to see if they are being accessed at all.

Answer (score 2):

IDMemberPath, ValueMemberPath, etc. are supposed to be property names, not bindings. Ie. IDMemberPath="QuoteID", etc.